# Sudo plugins not found

Tags: ubuntu, root

I was trying to give permission for myself to access root folder, since it was pretty much a nuisance for me. Hence I executed the following code in terminal.

```
cd /
sudo su
chmod 777 -R /root
```

And alas! That was the last time I executed a sudo command. Ever after that, if I execute a sudo command, I get the following error -

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I don't want to reboot the computer for the main reason that a lot of data of my project is stored. Also, I don't want to install all packages from the beginning again.

Of late, I realized that password also got modified.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/457164/cant-login-as-root-after-changing-permissions-of-usr-bin) is an answer. Hope it may help you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @suraznegi thx, it did

Comment: @melpomene never told it did

Comment: This is a site for programming questions.